# Using list of credentials to log into and preform tasks in bulk

Tags: python, text-files, paramiko

I have a text file called creds.txt with the format. I Want to be able to supply a text file with credentails to my ssh servers and run commands of all of them to make it easier to setup alot of ssh servers.

```
username:password:ip
```

I've ran the code bellow

```
import paramiko

with open('creds.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        usrname, passwd, ip = line.split(':')
        print("[!] trying " + usrname + " and " + passwd + " for " + ip)
        ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy)
        ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip, username=usrname, password=passwd, port=22)
        command = "ls"
        stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
        stdout = stdout.readlines()
        print (stdout)
        print("[+]connection succsessfull to " + ip + " with " + usrname + ":" + passwd)
        paramiko.agent.Agent.close
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/XXXX/Desktop/code projects/XXXX/XXXXXXXX.py", line 9, in <module>
    ssh_client.connect(hostname=ip, username=usrname, password=passwd, port=22)
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 340, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "E:\python\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 203, in _families_and_addresses
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "E:\python\lib\socket.py", line 918, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
PS C:\Users\Jaden\Desktop\code projects\net>
```

I've ran this without the code for the text file and it worked fine but when I added the file interpreting feature it stopped working.

Comment: Your error is `socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed`, which suggests you're passing it an invalid hostname or ip. Can you include in your question sample data that reproduces the problem? Also, have you considered something like [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), which is made for managing many hosts over ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that when you are splitting the text you are not stripping the remaining whitespace from the ip variable.

The lines in the file look like:
root:pass:127.0.0.1\r\n

The last part is the new line so I think the issue is that you haven't removed this so it can't connect to the ip. Try using the `strip()` or `rstrip()` function to remove this.

`ip.rstrip()`

Comment: I added the line `sip = ip.strip()` then assigned the `sip` variable to the host name.